# In Firebase realtime database, If i get link of database url at run time. Then how to fetch data from that url

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I get the database at the runtime of the function. So how to fetch data from that data base or how to make ref of that database.Like in below code i use the database url which i have knowledge but if i get the url of database as a request. Then how i can use it.

````
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Initialize the app with a null auth variable, limiting the server's access
admin.initializeApp({
  // The database URL depends on the location of the database
  databaseURL: "https://flysample-75b81.firebaseio.com",
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: null
});

// The app only has access to public data as defined in the Security Rules
let db = admin.database();

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.getDataFromDatabase = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    let nodeRef = request.query.rootNode;
    let ref = db.ref(`${nodeRef}`);
    ref.once('value', (snapshot)=> {
        response.send(snapshot.val());
    })
});```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the URL from the request that triggers the Cloud Function, you can call `initializeApp` and create the database object *inside* that function:

```
exports.getDataFromDatabase = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const url = ....; //  wherever you need to get this from is fine

  // Get or initialize an app for this URL with a null auth variable, limiting the server's access
  let app = getApp(url);
  if (!app) {
    app = admin.initializeApp({
      // The database URL depends on the location of the database
      databaseURL: "https://flysample-75b81.firebaseio.com",
      databaseAuthVariableOverride: null
    }, url);
  }
  // The app only has access to public data as defined in the Security Rules
  let db = app.database();

  let nodeRef = request.query.rootNode;
  let ref = db.ref(`${nodeRef}`);
  ref.once('value', (snapshot)=> {
      response.send(snapshot.val());
  })
});
```

In the above code we create or get an `app` for the database URL, using the same URL as the *name* of that app - so that we can look it up for that on future calls. We then use that specific app to get the database from.